# scikit-learn cross validation score in regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I'm trying to build a regression model, validate and test it and make sure it doesn't overfit the data. This is my code thus far:

```python
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, validation_curve
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array(read_csv('timeseries_8_2.csv', index_col=0))

inputs = data[:, :8]
targets = data[:, 8:]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    inputs, targets, test_size=0.1, random_state=2)

rate1 = 0.005
rate2 = 0.1

mlpr = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(12,10), max_iter=700, learning_rate_init=rate1)

# trained = mlpr.fit(x_train, y_train)  # should I fit before cross val?
# predicted = mlpr.predict(x_test)      

scores = cross_val_score(mlpr, inputs, targets, cv=5)
print(scores)
```

Scores prints an array of 5 numbers where the first number usually around 0.91 and is always the largest number in the array. 
I'm having a little trouble figuring out what to do with these numbers. So if the first number is the largest number, then does this mean that on the first cross validation attempt, the model scored the highest, and then the scores decreased as it kept trying to cross validate?

Also, should I fit the training the data before I call the cross validation function? I tried commenting it out and it's giving me more or less the same results.

Comment: Please understand about what cross-validation actually does. Start by [looking here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation). In this case, it will not fit the model for you to be used later. It just gives you the information about how a model is behaving with the data. The fitting needs to be done on the whole data once you are happy with the performance.

Comment: You may want to look into [TimeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-of-time-series-data)

Answer (score 2):

The cross validation function performs the model fitting as part of the operation, so you gain nothing from doing that by hand:

> The following example demonstrates how to estimate the accuracy of a linear kernel support vector machine on the iris dataset by splitting the data, fitting a model and computing the score 5 consecutive times (with different splits each time):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics

And yes, the returned numbers reflect multiple runs:

> Returns: Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score

Finally, there is no reason to expect that the first result is the largest:

```python
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
boston = datasets.load_boston()
est = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(120,100), max_iter=700, learning_rate_init=0.0001)
cross_val_score(est, boston.data, boston.target, cv=5)

# Output
array([-0.5611023 , -0.48681641, -0.23720267, -0.19525727, -4.23935449])
```

Comment: Ok, so what valuable information do you now know after getting the scores? I don't understand why they're helpful.

Comment: A classification task for the iris dataset would be more appropriate, since it is apparent that OP lacks basic knowledge about CV (and the scores you present might be confusing enough)

Comment: @desertnaut Agreed; updated with something more sensible.  swailem95: The scores allow you to quantify how well the model is doing (which becomes relevant for instance when having to choose between models); http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html contains quite a bit of information on the topic.

Comment: So if (in my case) the first score is the highest, does this mean that the model should only be cross validated once? Also, how could I see the training error to compare it with the validation errors?

Comment: If that really is the case, all that suggests is that the train/test splits are not random. Does the same thing happen if you use `cv=sklearn.model_selection.KFold(5, shuffle=True)` (cf. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold)? Regarding modifying the score, you can even supply a custom scorer; see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter

Comment: And to get both training and test scores, you can use `cross_validate`; see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#the-cross-validate-function-and-multiple-metric-evaluation